# using babel-loader with jhipster webpack config

Tags: webpack, babeljs, antd

Webpack is all black magic to me and I am trying to hack [jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/)'s webpack config to work with [babel-loader](https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import) so I can use [ant.d](https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started#Import-on-Demand). I have added `"babel-plugin-import": "^1.8.0"` to my deps and appended the following to package.json:

```
{
....
"babel": {
    "plugins": [["import", [
      {
        "libraryName": "antd",
        "libraryDirectory": "lib",   // default: lib
        "style": true
      },
      {
        "libraryName": "antd-mobile"
      },
    ]]]
  }
}
```

Once again this is all black magic for me and I am not quit sure which set of directions I should follow to get babel-loader to work with my webpage config. Let me know if you need to look at my other config files and I'll post them.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in your generated project's README on managing dependencies? https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app#managing-dependencies

Comment: If you look to my ant.d link it specifies that it's necessary to use babel-loader to import ant.d components or I would have to import the css and the fully qualified name from the package.